# Stop service when removing app through recent apps

Tags: android, eclipse, service

I have developed an app that plays bgm service even after hitting the home button or switching to another activity. The problem is when I remove the app through recent apps - the service is still running.

How do I make it stop when I remove the app through recent apps? Is it possible to do that?

here is my code:

```
public class MixPage extends Activity {

private ToggleButton creekToggle;
SharedPreferences creekPref;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mix);

    creekToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.creek);
    creekPref = getSharedPreferences("creekPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    creekToggle.setChecked(creekPref.getBoolean("is creek on",false));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void playCreek(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {
        Intent objCreek = new Intent(this, PlayCreek.class);
        startService(objCreek);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editorCreek=creekPref.edit();
        editorCreek.putBoolean("is creek on", true);
        editorCreek.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Creek is Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Intent objCreek = new Intent(this, PlayCreek.class);
        stopService(objCreek);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editorCreek=rainPref.edit();
        editorCreek.putBoolean("is creek on", false);
        editorCreek.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Creek is Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

PlayCrickets.java

```
public class PlayCrickets extends Service {
private static final String LOGCAT = null;
MediaPlayer objPlayer;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "Service Started!");
    objPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.crickets);
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    objPlayer.setLooping(true);
    objPlayer.start();
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "Media Player started!");
    if(objPlayer.isLooping() != true){
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "Problem in Playing Audio");
    return 1;
}

public void onStop() {
    objPlayer.stop();
    objPlayer.release();
}

public void onPause() {
    objPlayer.stop();
    objPlayer.release();
}

public void onDestroy(){
    objPlayer.stop();
    objPlayer.release();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent objIndent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    System.out.println("onTaskRemoved called");
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    objPlayer.stop();
    objPlayer.release();
    //stop service
    this.stopSelf();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your Manifest add stopWithTask attribute where you have define your service:

```
<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".YourService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:stopWithTask="true" />
```

If Above approach doest work then do reverse

```
<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:stopWithTask="false" />  //change to false
```

So your service's method onTaskRemoved will be called. (Remember, it won't be called if you set stopWithTask to true).

```
public class YourService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onStartService() {
        //your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        System.out.println("onTaskRemoved called");
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        //do something you want
        //stop service
        this.stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Comment: Update my answer check it out

Comment: it still not worked, i've been put the service code to my question.. it is right to put the onTaskRemoved there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `Service.onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)` in your service class. This method will get called when a task belonging to service application is removed from recent screen.
Do this:

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
    stopSelf();
}
```

Hope this will help.