# When to stop music in a music player

Tags: android, media, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle, exoplayer2.x

I am building a music player with exoplayer. I am using a separate service for music playback, but the problem is that the music continues playing even when I close the main activity by going to recents. I tried to solve this problem by stopping the service when onDestroy() is called. However this also stops the music service when back button is pressed. I checked both the cases in Musixmatch and it does stop if u close the app from recents but doesn't when you press the back button in the app even though I can see that the main activity is created again when the app is started again. So how can I achieve the same in my app?

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample android sound project - when I go to recent and 'close all' my audio stops. And using the goBack - you can pause, but if you dont it keeps playing.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.oldcar);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

public void goBack(View view){
    //mediaPlayer.pause();
    Log.i("info","ending audio activity");
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So we need to stop the service when the task is removed from the recents. For that you can have a look at the solution of ["stop service when remove app through recent app"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30690887/2644730).

It basically suggests to stop the service when `public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)` is called.

1).In your Manifest add stopWithTask attribute where you have define your service:

```
<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".YourService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:stopWithTask="true" />
```

2).If Above approach doest work then do reverse

```
<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:stopWithTask="false" />  //change to false
```

So your service's method onTaskRemoved will be called. (Remember, it won't be called if you set stopWithTask to true).

```
public class YourService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onStartService() {
        //your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        System.out.println("onTaskRemoved called");
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        //do something you want
        //stop service
        this.stopSelf();
    }
}
```